# Create process

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Добрый день, господа.

Был наслышан о функции `CreateProcessAsUser()`, но никак не могу в ней разобраться, кто с ней работал, привидите пожалуйста пример запуска программы на определенное время.

Приветствуются так же библиотеки, отличные от `windows.h`

Comment: Запуск по времени и CreateProcessAsUser() -- вещи разные. По данному вызову есть пример в MSDN. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: в msdn примеры с ужасным пояснением. Но разве нельзя запустить процесс на время, после чего получив результат?

Comment: @Arc, что Вы имеете в виду, когда пишите

    Но разве нельзя запустить процесс на время, после чего получив результат?

Запустить процесс, который через, скажем 5 секунд, будет остановлен системой?

Comment: Да, именно.

Comment: В \*nix можно было бы использовать `setrlimit()` с ресурсом `RLIMIT_CPU` при создании нового процесса (после `fork()` перед `exec`), а в Linux `prlimit()` позволяет менять лимиты уже запущенных процессов.

--

Что делать в винде? Быстро нагуглить не удалось. Может в ней подобное и не предусмотрено.

--

Другой вопрос (более принципиальный) это - а как в общем случае Вы собираетесь получать результат от остановленного процесса?

OK. Процесс получает сигнал SIGXCPU (все это относится к \*nix) и должен быть запрограммирован так, чтобы правильно отреагировать на такой сигнал.

Comment: блин, а что с виндой-то...

Comment: А Вы просто не программируйте в ней.

Comment: это же так просто. мне удобна винда и мне хорошо.